# Is this a bug in C# Enum.Parse()?

Tags: c#, enums

I get that my enum in this example is an Integer, but this still seems very wrong.  I expected an ArgumentException:

```
class Program {
    enum Testing {
        Zeroth,
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Testing result = Testing.Zeroth;
        var toTest = "17";
        result = (Testing)Enum.Parse(typeof(Testing), toTest);
        Console.WriteLine(result);  // Output: 17
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The following does throw the argument exception I expected:

```
    class Program {
    enum Testing {
        Zeroth,
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Testing result = Testing.Zeroth;
        var toTest = "Seventeen";
        result = (Testing)Enum.Parse(typeof(Testing), toTest);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And that takes the cake for me.

Comment: No, it is not a bug. There is an issue with your understanding though.

Comment: .NET doesn't check ranges of enums, cause it take a long time. Imagine f.e. the enum with 1000 items and values 1, 5, 3, 17, 28, ... and so on.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko It certainly violated the principle of least surprise.  You would think a variable, strongly typed to an enum, set by parsing through the Enum.Parse() method, would actually have meaning in terms of that enum.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko the question is not about ranges, but `Enum.Parse` method

Comment: @ie. The `Enum.Parse` doesn't check values, as well as all other methods. Nothing surprising.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Yet, if I give Guid.Parse() something that isn't a Guid, I get an ArgumentException.  I give Enum.Parse() something that doesn't resolve to the enum and yet I still get a variable typed to that enum with a value that is invalid in relation to the enum.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko agree, nothing surprising. I just noted that parse method irrelevant to the check of the ranges.

Comment: @jeromeyers, I agree. But C# is still used for industrial programming, therefore it doesn't contain some good bot not very fast decisions. And you always can add your own checking, if you need.

Comment: @jeromeyers: Use `Enum.IsDefined`