# C# Action/Function List

Tags: c#, function, enums, action

I have a program that has to execute a function acording to a Enum and I'm wondering If there's another way to it than this:

```
enum FunctionType
{
 Addition = 0,
 Substraction = 1,
 Mutiplication = 2,
 Division = 3
}
void ExecuteFunction(FunctionType Function)
{
  switch(Function)
  {
    case FunctionType.Addition: Addition();
    break;
    case FunctionType.Substraction: Subsctration();
    break;      
    ...
    default: ...  
  }
}
```

(This is not the code i'm using, it's just to represent what I want to do).
This approach should work fine, but what happens when you have much more functions? I don't want to have a 50 line switch. So I want to know if there's a way to simplify it, something like this maybe:

```
enum FunctionType : Action
{
 Addition = new Action(Addition);
 Substraction = new Action(Substraction);
 ....
}
void ExecuteFunction(FunctionType Function)
{
 (Action)Function.Invoke();
}
```

No switch is needed and what could be 50 lines turn into 1 line. But this is not possible to do, only numeric types are acceped as enums.
I think it's posible to have a `List<T>`  of actions but that would require to add each action to the list at runetime.

EDIT: 
I've found on a source code a way this is done, but I can't really understand It. This is what I get:
They create a custom `Attribute` that contains a `string` (The method name) and on the methods they do:

```
[CustomAtrribute("name")]
void Method()
{    
}
```

Then I don't know how this is called by it's name, I guess some kind of refelction, bu I don't know how to find the info about this.

EDIT2: I found the way I want to do this, I'll add an interface with a function, then implement that interface with the code inside the function and Use a `Dictionary<Enum, Interface>` to call it. I don't know If I should answer my own question, anyways, thanks to everyone one helped me.

Comment: Well you could have a `Dictionary<FunctionType, Action>`... but again, you'd need to build it up at execution time. If the method names all match the enum value names, you could do that via reflection though.

Comment: You can run an action by just appending `()`, no need to do `.Invoke()`. Just an fyi

Comment: @Jon Skeet Maybe the dictionary thing works fine, but adding everything doesn't sound good. Still better than a gigantic switch though. Making every method name match every enum name sounds a little dangerous when adding new things

Comment: Well you could add a unit test for it, of course. Ultimately, you haven't told us why you have the enum to start with. Why can your `ExecuteFunction` method not just take an `Action` or whatever?

Comment: I want to do this on a server and each value in the enum corresponds to a different type of packet, each packet is identified by a `int` value and parsed into the Enum. With a few diferent types of packets a switch would be just fine, but as I update the program I want to add more packets, and I want the code to be "clean", not a 50 case switch

Comment: Careful, parsing enums can be tricky:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219215/is-this-a-bug-in-c-sharp-enum-parse

Comment: I'm just casting them from a int, and I check first if the value exists. But thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Can't say I would recommend doing this but:

```
public static class Functions
{
    public static Func<int, int, int> Add = (x, y) => { return x + y; };
}
```

Then you just call `Functions.Add(1,1)`

If you really *have* to use an enum for it then you could do:

```
public static class Functions
{
    public static void Add()
    {
        Debug.Print("Add");
    }

    public static void Subtract()
    {
        Debug.Print("Subtract");
    }

    public enum Function
    {
        Add,
        Subtract
    }

    public static void Execute(Function function)
    {
        typeof(Functions).GetMethod(function.ToString()).Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Then `Functions.Execute(Functions.Function.Add)` (extra functions is because my enum was inside the Functions class).

Comment: This looks interesting, but would this have a performance impact when being called many times? Also why `.Invoke(null, null);`?

Comment: I tested this and the performance impact is pretty big, It takes x30 time if I input the name function as a string and x133 if I do `.ToString()` compared the regular function calling. If I load the methodInfo first it takes x20 time.

Comment: @null `.Invoke(null,null)` to call static method with no args, you may need to change it for your thing. Performance using reflection will be impacted heavily. I did say I suggest you don't. It might be worth examining if you are doing it the right way if you feel you need reflection. I can only answer your question because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. All that said, the performance penalty may be acceptable depending on your situation. Don't optimise prematurely.

Comment: I found a way to do what I wanted, I set a custom attribute with a string to the "functions" then I use reflection to get all functions with that attribute and add the to a Dictionary<string, delegate> so there's not that big of a performance impact, since I only use reflection once.

Answer (score 0):

If your functions contain same `signature` then you can do something like this

```
enum FunctionType
{
 Addition = 0,
 Substraction = 1,
 Mutiplication = 2,
 Division = 3
}
void ExecuteFunction(FunctionType Function)
{
  //variable will contain function to execute
  public Func<int, int, int> functionToExecute= null;

  switch(Function)
  {
    case FunctionType.Addition: functionToExecute=Addition;
    break;
    case FunctionType.Substraction: functionToExecute=Subsctration;
    break;      
    ...
    default: ...  
  }

  //Checking if not reached default case
  if(functionToExecute!=null)
  {
   var result= functionToExecute(para1,para2);
   ...............
  }


}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid the switch, that's the problem in the first place. If I have many functions the code would be too long.